# After upgrading 19.04 to 19.10 monitor dims and undims every few seconds

Tags: upgrade, 19.10

This is a desktop machine. Never happened on 19.04 and started from the first login to 19.10 - consequently, not a hardware changed issue. Happens with both HDMI and VGA connections.

[Link to the animated gif](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VQ7WnXs2sfCcow8HHNo_iJBp46QLNavt/view?usp=sharing) if the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should ensure that *Settings → Power → Automatic Brightness* is disabled.

[image: screenshot of Power, in Settings]

Comment: Haven't got this options under Power. Only "Blank Screen" and "Bluetooth"

Comment: Welcome to askUbuntu. Note that some systems(mostly laptops) use an embedded controller (EC) for power management( which includes brightness control to save power). You can attempt to override it. Open terminal and type `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power idle-brightness 100` and restart you system.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, it is the monitor itself that is failing - same problem when connecting to a different computer. Why this coincides with Ubuntu upgrade is a mystery.